# How would you find the MLE of this pairwise exponential distribution?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, exponential-distribution, estimators, point-estimation

$$X_1 \dots X_n \sim f_\theta(x) = \begin{cases}
\exp(\theta-x) & x\geq\theta\\
0& otherwise
\end{cases}$$

We have

$$L_x(\theta) = \begin{cases}
\exp(n\theta-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i) & x_i\geq\theta\;\;\forall i=1\dots n\\
0& otherwise
\end{cases}$$

But now I'm stuck. How do you find $\hat\theta$ from this?

EDIT: I see that $\theta=0$ might be the answer but it's just a hunch. I don't see a way to prove it.

EDIT: I think I figured it out

$$L_x(\theta) = \begin{cases}
\exp(n\theta-\sum_{i=1}^n x) & x_{(1)}\geq\theta\\\
0& otherwise
\end{cases}$$

So $\hat\theta = x_{(1)}$ which is just the smallest observation in our sample.

Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Could you explain what "pairwise exponential" means in the title?

Comment: @whuber sorry just see the distribution, that is what I meant, a pairwise function that is in part also exponential

Comment: The easy way to see what's going on is to simply draw the likelihood (or log-likelihood) function keeping in mind the constraint $x>\theta$. Simply choose a few (say three) plausible observations  and if it's not already obvious by then, compute the log-likelihood at a sequence of values (in R or Excel or whatever, if you wish) and plot them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are right, the $\hat{\theta}=x_{(1)}$ is the mle for the distribution.

Since your parameter $\theta$ in the support $x \ge \theta$ differentiation does not work here.

But you can write you likelihood functin as
$$L(\theta) = 
\exp(n\theta-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)I(\theta,min\left\{x_i\right\})$$

Where $I(a,b)$ is an indicator function which is equal to $1$ when $a \le b$ and $0$ when $a >b$.

You can see in term of $\theta$, $exp(n\theta-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)$ is an increasing fucntion therefore maximum value of $L(\theta)$ occurs at $min\left\{x_i\right\}$. i.e the maximum possilbe value of $\theta$

$\therefore \hat{\theta}=min\left\{x_i\right\}=x_{(1)}$

By the way, I think you should write $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ not $\sum_{i=1}^n x$

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice approach that I haven't seen before although I guess it's the same reasoning